# Interpreting the constant when performing a fixed effect panel data regression in Stata

Tags: statistics, finance, data-analysis

Dear Stackexchange community,

I am running a panel data regression on 20 years of monthly historical excess returns of the stocks in the S&P 500 at 31/12/2017. I like to test the effectiveness of several factor models, however I am having difficulty interpreting the constant that Stata provides. If I recall correctly, when using a fixed effect model the equation when using one independent variable is as follows.

$$Y_{i,t}=βX_{i,t}+α_i+u_{i,t}$$

where $\alpha_i$ is an individual intercept per stock.

When I perform a fixed effect panel data regression of my dataset on the monthly excess market return provided by Kenneth French on his website, stata gives me a constant. How should I interpret that? My regression result was as follows:

My regression then would follow this equation right?:

$$r_{i,t}-r[\text{risk free}]_t= β(r[mkt]_t-r[\text{risk free}]_t)+α_i+u_{i,t}$$

my regression result is the following:
[panel data regression result (xtreg, fe)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFzu6.png)

as you can see, it includes a constant. How do I interpret this?

any help would be greatly appreciated!
kind regards,

Marinus

Comment: I'd want to see a more explicit description of the problem before attempting to say anything. For example, you say only obliquely that the index $i$ tells you which stock it is. Also, I think this might get better answers at stats.stackexchange.com than here.

Comment: i indeed represents the stock, t stands for the time period. Since I have monthly returns of 21 year, t goes from 1 tot 252. Alpha stands for the intercept and u is the error term. Beta is the coëfficiënt with the market index. Perhaps the problem is more clear when I state it like this: in the first equation alpha has a subscript, meaning that every stock has an individual intercept. Yet Stata seems to give one universal intercept. That is what causes my confusion. Thanks for the suggestion about stats.stackexchange, I will also check that out.

Comment: If the issue is why  you get only a single intercept rather than one for each value of $i,$ then I wonder if that's something about the way you're using the software.